# How to kill an asyncio coroutine (not First_completed case)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, future, concurrent.futures

There is an example: `main` coroutine creates coroutines that take a long time to complete, what means `FIRST_COMPLETED` case is unreachable. Problem: considering that `await asyncio.wait(tasks)` line blocks everything under itself, how to get access to pending futures set?

```
import asyncio

async def worker(i):
    #some big work
    await asyncio.sleep(100000)

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(worker(i), name=str(i)) for i in range(5)]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks) #or asyncio.as_completed(tasks, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED) no matter
    # everything below is unreachable until tasks are in process
    # we want to kill certain task
    for future in pending:
        if future.get_name == "4":
            future.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How to avoid await block and kill certain coroutine? for example 4?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, if you don't want to wait for even one task to complete why using `asyncio.wait` at all?

Comment: to start tasks execution

Comment: You don’t need it, they start as soon as you create them.

Comment: it doesnt work to me coz without await all child koroutines will break when parent koroutine is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another task to monitor your tasks:

```
async def monitor(tasks):
    # monitor the state of tasks and cancel some
    while not all(t.done() for t in tasks):
        for t in tasks:
            if not t.done() and t.get_name() == "4":
                t.cancel()
            # ...
        # give the tasks some time to make progress
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(worker(i), name=str(i)) for i in range(5)]
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(monitor(tasks[:])))
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    # ...
```